# Android Studio won't start at all to be use in React Native project

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run android studio emulator using `Pixel 2 API 28` and `Pixel 3a API 28` but whenever I try to launch the emulator by clicking the play button, it always show the dialog box below and won't even start the android at all.

[image]

Tried to search online resource but I did not find any solution or idea what's causing this.

I am trying to work with React Native.

Please help!

Comment: Did you try killing and restarting adb? Did you try deleting the AVD and creating a new one? Did you try rolling back your version of Android Emulator? Did you try reinstalling Android Studio and Android SDK?

Comment: Recently I face similar issue like you, an emulator been using for awhile just didn't work in a sudden. I then re-create a new simulator with recommended image ...